# EXCEL VBA Dynamic Sheet Name according to a cell value - Not working when formula in the cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Hej,

I've created a small VBA code to dynamically rename a worksheet.

It's working perfectly when the cell is just manually typed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C9")

    End If
End Sub
```

But then as soon as I will put a formula concatenating 2 cells values within C9 cell it will not update it automatically. 
To make it work I need to enter the cell and type ENTER again and it works.
I have to do same manipulation each time I change a value in on of the 2 cell concatenated.

THANKS for your help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture a **different event**:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C9")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

We disable events during the name change in case the worksheet contains a formula referencing the tab-name.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

replace

`ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C9")`

by

`ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value`

Comment: the line If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C9")) Is Nothing Then is the Problem. You only look for changes in the formula if this cell. Leave it away then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate answer if someone still wants to execute this on worksheet change event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim formulacell As Range
    Set formulacell = Range("C9")
    Set formulacell = Application.Union(formulacell, formulacell.Precedents)

    If Not Intersect(Target, formulacell) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```